# JSON obtain value from key in Python

Tags: python, json, parsing, json-value

I have this Python script:

```
import json
from cinbase.walle.client import Client

apiKey = foo
mysecret = bar

client = Client( apiKey, mySecret )
price = client.get_spot_price(currency_pair = 'BTC-EUR')
```

This is my output:

```
{
"data" :{
             "amount": "123455"
             "currency": "EUR"
 }
}
```

How to get only "amount" value?

Comment: output_obj['data']['amount']

Comment: how did you produce the output? did you just print the "price" variable?

Answer (score 2):

In python, this data type is called a dict (short for dictionary). You can index this object as follows:

```
value = your_dict[key]
```

So in your case specifically:

```
amount = price["data"]["amount"]
```

Comment: Thanks for explaination @ahammond! I have solved